# How do I set an image in MenuItem?

Tags: java

here is my code below, instead of trying to setTitle, i'm trying to setImage/Icon in my placeholder but can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. Can anyone help me with this?

```
 private void setOptionTitle(String title){
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.points);
    item.setTitle(title);

}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.points).setTitle(getString(R.string.app_currency).toUpperCase()+" : " + App.getInstance().getBalance());

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code example:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.filter_point);    
item.setIcon(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(R.drawable.your_vector_icon);
```

or you can do it like this:

```
item.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.your_vector_icon));
```